# Having trouble with Requests.get()

Tags: python, list, request, python-requests

Following code worked yesterday, now it gets hung in terminal, giving error `list index out of range`, however when I run the same code using IDE it works perfectly.

I do not understand what is going on. And no the url isn't invalid.

```
import requests  
import bs4  
import webbrowser       
import csv


def CheckStock(url):  
'''checks for shoes in stock'''  
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}  
    RawHTML = requests.get(url, headers=headers)  
    Page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(RawHTML.text, "lxml")  
    ListOfRawSizes = Page.select('.size-dropdown-block')  
    Sizes = str(ListOfRawSizes[0].getText()).replace('\t', '')  
    Sizes = Sizes.replace('\n\n', ' ')  
    Sizes = Sizes.split()  
    Sizes.remove('Select')  
    Sizes.remove('size')  
    return Sizes
```

Comment: `print(ListOfRawSizes)` will help you

Comment: What are you trying to do? And what is the detailed error, like trackback? Did you try to print the variable to ensure it is as expected? Or use `pdb` to debug this program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is if your page doesn't contain any elements with a `.size-dropdown-block` class, your `ListOfRawSizes[0]` index will be out of range. You can't ask for the first item in a list if the list is empty, that will throw the `index out of range` error. This is most likely caused by the page being different from the previous day to when you tried it now.

You need to check if `ListOfRawSizes` has any items in it before trying to index the list. Fortunately, python makes it easy to check if a list is empty, `if ListOfRawSizes:` will be true if the list has at least one item.

```
ListOfRawSizes = Page.select('.size-dropdown-block')

# check to see if the list of raw sizes is not empty
if ListOfRawSizes:
    # we have at least one size so get the first item and do our work
    Sizes = str(ListOfRawSizes[0].getText()).replace('\t', '')  
    Sizes = Sizes.replace('\n\n', ' ')  
    Sizes = Sizes.split()  
    Sizes.remove('Select')  
    Sizes.remove('size')  
    return Sizes
# if we hit the else clause, our list must be empty
else:
    # ...so return an empty list
    return []
```

Additionally, you really shouldn't name your variables starting with capital letters. This could very easily conflict with class names. Variables in Python follow "snake case" convention; All lowercase with underscores to separate words. (eg: `this_is_snake_case`).

Comment: Thanks very much you mind if i ask you another question about the requests module?

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum; You can ask another question on Stack Overflow separately. If this answer solved your most immediate problem, mark it correct, then create the new question.

Comment: alright i did, do you mind checking it out? https://stackoverflow.com/q/44428365/8095150